# Jackson JSON gives exception on collection of nested class

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

Jackson JSON has no problem serializing/deserializing this class:

```
public class MyClass {
   public class Nested {
      public String string;
      public Nested() {}
   }
   public Nested nestedVar;
}
```

but on this one:

```
public class MyClass {
   class Nested {
      public String string;
      public Nested() {}
   }
   public Nested nestedVar;
   public List<Nested> nestedList;
}
```

I get this exception when deserializing:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class test.MyClass$Nested]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
>    at [Source: java.io.StringReader@26653222; line: 1, column: 48] (through reference chain: test.MyClass["nestedList"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])

In the first case, Jackson has no problem dealing with an instance of a nested class, but not in the second case.

Must I write a custom deserializer?

Test code (Jackson 2.6.3):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ATest {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

      StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

      MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

      MyClass.Nested nestedVar = myClass.new Nested();

      List<MyClass.Nested> nestedList = new ArrayList<>();

      nestedList.add(nestedVar);

      myClass.nestedList =nestedList;

      myClass.nestedVar = nestedVar;

      mapper.writeValue(sw, myClass);

      System.out.println(sw.toString());

      StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.toString());

      MyClass z = mapper.readValue(sr, MyClass.class);
}
```

}

Comment: try creating a object of list or atleast set public List<Nested> nestedList = null;

Comment: try to make inner class static.

Comment: nestedList = null does not work

Comment: I don't want to make the inner class accessible outside the outer class, if I really must I will write a custom deserializer

Comment: nestedList = new ArrayList<>() also does not work

Comment: Can you please provide a runnable example, because your second class works fine for me.

Comment: Added test code in question

Comment: Thanks for the test code. About `static` for your nested class: it would avoid the issue you have here and the argument *"I don't want to make the inner class accessible outside the outer class"* is not affected by `static`. Currently `Nested` is package-private in your example and you could keep it that way.

Comment: Thanks. I have actually mistyped the code - Nested is actually declared as public (now corrected). What I want is that you can make a Nested from another package, but it should always live in a MyClass, not exist on its own (as it would if it were declared static public).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like the recognition of non-static inner classes is done where they are properties directly on their containing bean (`BeanDeserializerBase.java` line 476 in 2.6.3). So an intervening Collection deserializer would go past that. A custom deserializer is likely the simplest option here.

Note that you can still use Jackson to read the properties of `Nested`, and just implement the construction of it yourself, in a custom deserializer *only* used when deserializing a list of `Nested` objects.

To do this, annotate the list like so:

```
    @JsonDeserialize(contentUsing = NestedDeserializer.class)
    public List<Nested> nestedList;
```

and then use a custom deserializer that will:

1. Look at the parsing context when called to find the containing `MyClass` instance.
2. Encapsulate a default/root-level deserializer of `Nested` to delegate the work of deserializing the content to.

For example:

```
public static final class NestedDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<MyClass.Nested>
    implements ResolvableDeserializer {
  private JsonDeserializer<Object> underlyingDeserializer;

  public NestedDeserializer() {
    super(MyClass.Nested.class);
  }

  @Override
  public void resolve(DeserializationContext ctxt) throws JsonMappingException {
    underlyingDeserializer = ctxt
        .findRootValueDeserializer(ctxt.getTypeFactory().constructType(MyClass.Nested.class));
  }

  @Override
  public Nested deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    JsonStreamContext ourContext = p.getParsingContext();
    JsonStreamContext listContext = ourContext.getParent();
    JsonStreamContext containerContext = listContext.getParent();
    MyClass container = (MyClass) containerContext.getCurrentValue();
    MyClass.Nested value = container.new Nested();
    // note use of three-argument deserialize method to specify instance to populate
    underlyingDeserializer.deserialize(p, ctxt, value);
    return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Spot on!
I actually ended up doing something not so clean - using @jsondeserialize, but with a custom builder that would just generate a Nested from a temp MyClass, and return it. But this is the textbok way. Thanks!

Comment: Very super solution